# React-Native : how show loading screen before list view populated

Tags: react-native

Here is my code .I am using ***ComponentwillMount Function for API*** and then using **isLoading** variable and accordingly displaying the particular view.**But its doesnt work**...  its seems to be I done something wrong please took a glance and help me out I am new to react - native

```
const UserPage = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(dataList),
            isLoading:true
        }
    },

    componentWillMount() {

        SharedPreferences.getItem("sender_id", (value) => {
            let user_id = value;
            let url = "BaseURL/fetchSendTokens?user_id="+user_id;
            fetch(url, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseData) => {
                    if (responseData.responsecode === 1) {
                        dataList = responseData.data;
                        this.setState = ({
                            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(dataList),
                            isLoading:false,
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        ToastAndroid.show('Please try again...', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                    }
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    ToastAndroid.show('Please try again...', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                })
                .done();
        });
    },


    renderRow(rowData, sectionID,){

        let  currentView = (rowData.visitor_profileImageUrl)?
            <Image
                source={{uri:rowData.visitor_profileImageUrl}}
                style={{height:40,width:40,margin:15,borderRadius:100}}
                resizeMode="contain"/> :
            <Image
                source={userprofilepic}
                style={{height:40,width:40,margin:15,borderRadius:100}}
                resizeMode="contain"/>;

        return <View key={ sectionID }>
            <View style={{ flex: 1,height:70,flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View>
                    {currentView}
                </View>
                <Text style={{fontSize : 18,marginTop:15,marginLeft:20,color:"black"}} >{ rowData.visitor_name }</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    },

    render() {
        let loadingGif = "URL-loading.gif";
        let currentView = (this.state.isLoading)?<View style={styles.background}>
                <View style={styles.markWrap}>
                    <Image source={{uri:loadingGif}} style={styles.verifyLogo} resizeMode="contain"/>
                </View>
            </View>:
            <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow} enableEmptySections={true}/>;

        return(
            <View>
                {currentView}
            </View>
        );

    },
});
```

Comment: Don't alter the state in render!

Comment: So how is it not working?

Comment: thats what I am asking.....

Comment: No, I'm asking you to describe what happens so that we can understand the issue you're having.

Comment: the problem here is listview is not loaded instead the blank screen is displayed but when i push the same page again...the lsitview is populated

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a typo:

```
                    this.setState = ({
                        datasource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(dataList),
                        isLoading:false,
                    })
```

Should be:

```
                    this.setState = ({
                        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(dataList),
                        isLoading:false,
                    })
```

Note that you seem to keep around a global `dataSource` and `dataList` - that's usually not a good practice. If you need to keep data, use props and callbacks to pass it around, not globals.

Comment: same problem persist  and how to use props and callbacks to pass it around

Comment: I think loading taking time so thats why listview is not populated and white screen comes

Answer (score 0):

```
    constructor(props){
       super(props);

       this.state = {
         loading: true,
       }

    } 

    render(){
       if (this.props.loading) {
              return (<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}><ActivityIndicator
                animating={states.campaign.loading}
                style={[styles.centering, { height: 80 }]}
                size="large"
              /></View>);
            }else{
              return (<ListView></ListView>);
            }
}
```

Comment: I am using this  React.createClass()

Comment: i suggest use the new format like class UserPage extends Component {}, there won't be much change in code. More over you can achieve the same with your format also

Comment: but is the solution for above problem I think loading taking time so thats why listview is not populated and white screen comes

Comment: might be list data is empty. you can put console.log or attach debugger to check for the actual issue.

Comment: Yup the data is empty on time of first load but on second time its populated any solutions?

Comment: Try to keep data in state instead of data source. Check ListView documentation for the same

Comment: is there any way to use the same thing  using React.createClass()

Comment: how to keep data in state instead of data source.I have read the document but didn't find relevant solution